# Broadcast Receiver onReceive method not called when screen/cpu goes off

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I am working on an application that will notify me (by playing a ringtone) that battery level has reached certain level. Level is configurable. For this I have created an activity that starts a service which in turn registers a receiver for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`.

*MyActivity -> MyService -> MyBrodcastReceiver [ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED] -> onReceive() -> if(Battery Level <= MyValue) -> play ringtone*

Everything works fine as long as screen is on but as soon as phone is locked and screen goes off or CPU sleeps the broadcast receiver’s `onReceive` method doesn’t get called and when I unlock phone again everything works. I verified this with logging.

Is it that `onReceive` method for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` gets called only when phone screen is on and stops when phone sleeps?

I even tried using Wake Lock in `onReceive` method but that didn’t work 

[I am testing with ICS (4.0.4)]

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;


public class BatteryMeterService extends Service {

    private BatteryStatusReceiver batteryStatusReceiver;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        batteryStatusReceiver = new BatteryStatusReceiver(null); 
        registerReceiver(batteryStatusReceiver, intentFilter);      
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(batteryStatusReceiver);
    }

}


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.amol.bm.BatteryMeterUtility.NotificationInfo;

public class BatteryStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    private BatteryMeterUtility batteryMeterUtility;

    public BatteryStatusReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        float fPct = (level / (float)scale) * 100;
        int levelPct = (int)fPct; 

        boolean prefAlertLowBattery = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("prefAlertLowBattery", true);
        if(prefAlertLowBattery) {
                String prefAlertLowBatteryValue = sharedPrefs.getString("prefAlertLowBatteryValue", "20");
                int lowBatteryValue = Integer.parseInt(prefAlertLowBatteryValue);
                if(levelPct <= lowBatteryValue && iStatus != BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING) {
                notificationInfo.icon = R.drawable.low_battery;
                PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "BM WakeLook");
                wakeLock.acquire();
                batteryMeterUtility.playAlertRingtone(alertRingtone);
                wakeLock.release();
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You could define the permission for WAKE_LOCK in manifest and check.

Comment: Are you unregistering the receiver anywhere in your code ?? Probably in onPause ??

Comment: Not in onPause but in OnDestroy of service but I checked through log that service's onDestroy is not getting called.

Comment: Could you try registering your receiver in the manifest file and check ?

Comment: You cannot register ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED  in manifest. "You can not receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver()." Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED

Comment: What is the problem you are facing after using WAKE_LOCK ?

Comment: My problem is OnReceive method is not getting called when screen if off even after using WAKE_LOCK

Comment: Where are you starting and stopping the service ?

Comment: I'm starting service onDestroy of my activity and stopping it onCreate. As I want it to be running in background only and don't want to be running when my activity is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used Alarm Manager with RTC_WAKEUP to solve this problem. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 1):

You should give WAKE_LOCK Permission to your service running in background so that even when the phone is Idle or goes off your service keeps on running. hope you got it let me know if unclear

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean by giving permission to service. I have added user-permission for WAKE_LOCK in manifest file. Also I THINK my service is running even when screen is off.

Comment: can you show your code i.e the service and broadcast receiver

Comment: Sure. But currently I'm out. Will post the code as soon as I'm home. But to give you idea - In service onCreate() method I am registering a broadcast listener and in onDestroy un-registering it. In broadcast receiver in onReceive method I am checking battery level and playing a ringtone using mediaplayer. Anyways will post the code .